# How to Print the invalid input in a error message? C++

Tags: c++, codeblocks

The Idea is to invoke a single function to check the user input and return True || False.

User Input with 0123456789 must return

> The Number Entered Correctly

User Input with 0123w456789 must return

> Number is not allowed or Contains invalid input such as "w"

User Input with 0123wx456789 must return

> Number is not allowed or Contains invalid input such as "wx"

My Code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main ( )
{
    string i_numvalidation;
    cout << "Enter the number: " << '\n';
    cin >> i_numvalidation;

    bool isNumber = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < i_numvalidation.length();  i++)
    {
        if (!(i_numvalidation[i] >= '0' && i_numvalidation [i] <= '9'))
        {
            isNumber = false;
        }
    }
    if (isNumber)
        cout << " Entered number " << i_numvalidation << " is correct" << '\n';
    else
        cout << " Entered number " << i_numvalidation << " is not allowed or Contains invalid input such as " << "'\n";
}
```

Question is Updated to understand it clearly.

Comment: When you find a non-digit save it in a variable so you can print it later.

Comment: @BessieTheCow Even better, just save the value of `i` that broke it.

Answer (score 1):

You already have almost everything you need to get the desired output. You only need to remember the characters that make the input invalid (ie those for which you set `isNumber = false;`) in a second string and print that instead of the original input. Really the only ingredient that you are not already using in your code is adding a character to a string and that can be done like this:

```
std::string x;
char invalid_character = 'w';
char other_invalid_character = 'p';
x += invalid_charater;
x += other_invalid_character;
std::cout << x; // prints wp
```

Comment: What if the user input is 0123q456789 or 0123qx456789 ?

Comment: @Arnold-Baba I assumed you want to print all non-digits on the error message (otherwise you could break out of the loop on the first non-digit found). Inside the loop you can add any non-digit to a string and print that.

Comment: Its mean I must add every single combination of non digits? and how it will check and print all the invalid characters even if I add all those thousands combinations?

Comment: @Arnold-Baba what thousand combinations? You take the user input, inspect every character of it, if you encounter a non-digit you set `isNumber = false;` (so far this is your code only), then you can remember all non-digit characters and print them on the error message (this is what I thought you want)

Comment: @Arnold-Baba what do you want to print on the error when input is `0123qx456789` ? only `q` or `qx` ?

Comment: Definitely I will print "qx" and if the input is 0123ab4567pl89 then I want to print  "ab" "pl"

Comment: @Arnold-Baba then sorry, but I don't understand what you don't understand

Comment: It's ok, So I have implemented some functions and I will post the new answer in some minutes for my question and I want that you please debug it if I have any errors thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The Functions I have Implemented is working for a single value but it is still not printing the complete invalid characters.
If the Input is 0123ab456789 so it will print the error message with "a" instead of "ab". It must print "ab" as input contains "ab".

The Code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ( )
{
string i_numvalidation;
cout << "Enter the Number: " << '\n';
cin >> i_numvalidation;
bool isNumber = true;
int bad_index = 0 ;
if (i_numvalidation [0] == '0')
    isNumber = false;
for (int i = 0; i < i_numvalidation.length () && isNumber; i++ )
{
    if (!(i_numvalidation [i] >= '0' && i_numvalidation [i] <= '9'))
{
        isNumber = false;
        bad_index = i ;
        break;
}
    }
    if (isNumber)
        {
        cout << "  The Entered " << i_numvalidation << " number is correct" << '\n';
    }
    else
            cout << " The Entered " << i_numvalidation << " is not allowed or Contains invalid input such as '" << i_numvalidation [ bad_index ] << "'\n";

}
```

Comment: You posted this as an answer however from your text I don't think this solves the problem.

Comment: @drescherjm That's why I am not accepting my own answer.

Comment: Please don't post answers that are not a solution. Instead edit your question. The answer section is to help future readers with the same problem. StackOverflow is not a forum.

Comment: @drescherjm The question is simple to read and understand, I answered it to extend the question so people will have 2 examples to practice and find the solution quickly

Comment: I see I guess the good point is that in this answer you don't ask how to fix your answer to get what you wanted. Those type of answers I would flag to be deleted.

Comment: @drescherjm I have Already mention that  If the Input is 0123ab456789 so it will print the error message with "a" instead of "ab".

Answer (score -1):

Like:

```
String err='1';
for(int i=0;i<i_numvalidation.length(); i++)
{
  if(i_numvalidation[i]!= '0' || i_numvalidation[i]!= '1' || i_numvalidation[i]!= '2' and so on...)
{
    err[err.length()]=i_numvalidation[i];
    isNumber=false;
}
}
if(!isNumber)
  cout<<"That's not a number bruh"<<err<<endl;
```

Sorry if I'm not helpful, I tried...
Hope you'll get the answer.

Comment: Thank you for trying but by using ASCII we can do it by an easy method such as: if (!(i_numvalidation [i] >= '0' && i_numvalidation [i] <= '9'))  and we can replace 0 with 48 and 9 with 57

Comment: Someone Down Vote your answer, if they don't like your answer they must ignore it instead of down vote.

Comment: Right...Lmao, didn't think abt that